# Coloring arithmetic progression

Tags: combinatorics, arithmetic-progressions, ramsey-theory, probabilistic-method

I've been looking at some old notes from the course Probabilistic Combinatorics and I saw the following question:

> Prove that there exists a constant $N$ and a red/blue coloring of $\mathbb{Z}$ without any monochromatic $n$-term arithmetic progressions with $n \geq N$ and common difference less than $1.99^n$.

The question appeared under the section about Lovasz Local lemma (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lov%C3%A1sz_local_lemma) so i'm assuming there is a way using it. I was trying to define the events to be the existence of a monochromatic $n-$term AP with a specific difference however it did not work.

ANY help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, to get a result about colorings of $\mathbb Z$ using the probabilistic method, we need to get there in two steps. First, we prove that an arbitrarily large interval $[-M,M] \cap \mathbb Z$ can be colored. Second, we use a compactness argument to pass to $\mathbb Z$. Assuming that the course notes cover the second step, I'll focus on the first.

As our bad events for the local lemma, we take all individual arithmetic progressions (of length $n \ge N$ and common difference less than $1.99^n$) contained in this interval. If $A$ is a bad event corresponding to an arithmetic progression of length $n$, we'll take $x(A) = 1.995^{-n}$; note that $\Pr[A] = 2^{1-n}$, so this allows $x(A)$ to be exponentially larger than $\Pr[A]$.

An arithmetic progression of length $n$ intersects at most $nk \cdot 1.99^{k}$ arithmetic progressions of length $k$: we choose in $nk$ ways which terms of the two progressions overlap, and in $1.99^{k}$ ways the common difference of the other progression. So we have
\begin{align}
   x(A) \prod_{B \in \Gamma(A)} (1 - x(B)) &\ge 1.995^{-n} \prod_{k=N}^\infty (1 - 1.995^{-k})^{nk \cdot 1.99^k} \\
  &= \left(\frac1{1.995} \prod_{k=N}^\infty (1 - 1.995^{-k})^{k \cdot 1.99^k}\right)^n \\
  &\ge \left(\frac1{1.995} \left(1 - \sum_{k=N}^\infty  k \left(\frac{1.99}{1.995}\right)^k\right)\right)^{n}.
\end{align}
In the last step, we turn the product into a sum by repeated use of the inequality $(1-x)(1-y) \ge 1 - x - y$ when $x,y \ge 0$.

The sum as $k$ goes from $N$ to $\infty$ is convergent, so by choosing $N$ sufficiently large, we can make it as small as we like. Let's choose $N$ to be large enough that it is less than $0.001$ (we'll have another condition on $N$ later). Then
$$
   x(A) \prod_{B \in \Gamma(A)} (1 - x(B)) \ge \left(\frac1{1.995}(1 - 0.001)\right)^n = \left(\frac{999}{1995}\right)^n.
$$
Our second condition on $N$ is that it must be large enough that $(\frac{999}{1995})^N \ge 2 \cdot (\frac12)^N$; then the same inequality holds for all $n \ge N$, and tells us that
$$
   x(A) \prod_{B \in \Gamma(A)} (1 - x(B)) \ge 2^{1-n} = \Pr[A].
$$
Now we know that the condition in the local lemma holds, so we can avoid all these arithmetic progressions.

Comment: Misha - thank you very much for your answer!